# Unidentified form flask Jinja template attribute model

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create an edit form in flask, to compliment my working add and delete form - but I'm getting an error about items not being defined.

The template I have:

```
% extends "main/_base.html" %}
{% block title %}Edit Item{% endblock %}
{% from "main/_formshelper.html" import render_field %}

{% block content %}

<form action="{{ url_for('main.edit_item', items_id=item.Items.id) }}" method="post" name="edititemsform">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.name.label }}
      {{ render_field(form.name, class="form-control", value=item.name) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.notes.label }}
      {{ render_field(form.notes, class="form-control", value=item.notes) }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit Item" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The view that drives it:

```
@main_blueprint.route("/edit_item/<int:items_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_item(items_id):
    form = EditItemsForm(request.form)
    item_with_user = db.session.query(Items).filter(Items.id == items_id).first()
    if item_with_user is not None:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                if form.validate_on_submit():
                    try:
                        item = Items.query.get(items_id)
                        item.name = form.name.data
                        item.notes = form.notes.data
                        db.session.commit()
                        flash('Item edited')
                        return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))
                    except:
                        db.session.rollback()
                        flash('Item edit error')
            return render_template('main/edit_item.html', item=item_with_user, form=form)
    else:
        flash('Item does not exist')
    return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))
```

The error I get is :

```
 jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'app.main.models.Items object' has no attribute 'Items'
```

This is my model which I think is the root of the issue, is it that is looking for Items inside my model Items?

```
from app import db

class Items(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    notes = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, name, notes):
        self.name = name
        self.notes = notes

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the URL for the form's action parameter, you are referencing an incorrect attribute. You've already passed an `Items` object to the template and now you just need to request the `id` attribute and pass it to `url_for`.

```html
<form 
  action="{{ url_for('main.edit_item', items_id=item.id) }}" 
  method="post" 
  name="edititemsform"
>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

In order not to manually assign a value to every input field within the template, I recommend that you simply assign the object to be edited to the form. The `validate_on_submit` function then checks whether the request is of the `POST` type and whether the input is valid. Then you can use `populate_obj` to update all existing attributes. The database entry is then saved by `commit`.

```py
@main_blueprint.route("/edit_item/<int:items_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_item(items_id):
    item = Items.query.get_or_404(items_id)
    form = EditItemsForm(request.form, obj=item)
    if form.validate_on_submit(): 
        form.populate_obj(item)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Item edited')
            return redirect(url_for('main.all_items'))
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
            flash('Item edit error')
    return render_template('main/edit_item.html', **locals())
```